# Is Vector axis in unity implicitly applied for all objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a beginner in unity and tried make a simple game named pong.

My tutorial taught me to choose 2 separate axes. I chose Vertical for my Left Racket and Vertical1 for my right racket. However, when I used the Down and Up arrow keys, both rackets moved. Surprisingly, using "W" and "S" keys can move my left one separately.

I experimented another choice by assigning Vertical2 for Left Racket. This time, my problem was solved.

These are images of my game:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my code (C#) for moving the rackets:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveRacket : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 30;
    public string axis="Vertical";

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw(axis);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, v) * speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `Vertical1` config look like?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html maybe this could help? :)

Comment: You may have had `s` and `w` configured as alt buttons on `Vertical1`

Comment: Could you show your code?